# Unable to create first application on yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I recently installed yii framework on my Mac. But I'm unable to create my first project.

I run this command

```html
cd Documents/Websites/radiofree.dev.cc/yii/basic

Documents/Websites/radiofree.dev.cc/yii/basic/framework/yiic.php webapp sarath
```

I can't find the directory called "framework" under the yii/basic

But it looks yii installed successfully & I can access the homepage.

Please help to create first application

Comment: are you using Yii1 or Yii2 ? ..  yiic (if i remember correctly) is for yii1 .. for yii2 you could take a look at  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation

Comment: I installed Yii2.

Comment: How I can create a new web project ?,

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're mixing versions.

`framework/yiic.php` is for Yii 1 (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app) while you're stating in comments that you installed Yii 2.

Try the Yii 2 installation instructions instead: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#installing-from-composer

Answer (score -1):

first of all you need to install the composer after that

-Setup Composer plugin

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

For Basic Project (Which doesn't require backend or other sub applications)

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

For Advanced Project (with backend, frontend)

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced your-yii-application
```